HttpClient.GetAsync(url) throwing exception when run in an Azure App/Function
I have the following piece of code in an Azure Function:
[Function("GetHtml")]
public async Task GetHtml(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    try
    {
        var url = $"https://www.stepstone.de/jobs/ausbildung/in-deutschland?page=1";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var streamResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
}

Everything works well when I execute this on my local machine.
But, when I publish to Azure and try to run the same piece of code,
I get an error on line 4: httpClient.GetAsync(url)

An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[Error]   An error occurred while sending the request.


StackTrace:    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at AzureHtmlTest.FunctionApp.Function1.GetHtml(HttpRequest req) in C:\10_ProjectFiles\Fujour\2024.09.05

Strangely, all is fine if I change the url to "https://www.google.com/search?q=Ausbildung". It works from both local as well as when published on Azure.
Things I have tried so far without luck:

Publishing to an Azure App (No change)
Setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
Setting httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
Setting httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Timeout", "30000");

I have been breaking my head for the past 2 days on this, and have all but given up. Please help!

Can you share your complete code in the question?

Done. Added the full function code.

I added the below code to access the URL in the HTTP trigger function.
httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
await Task.Delay(1000); 

Below is the complete HTTP trigger function code to access the URL.
Function1.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public class HtmlFetcherFunction
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        });
        private readonly ILogger<HtmlFetcherFunction> _logger;
        public HtmlFetcherFunction(ILogger<HtmlFetcherFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [Function("GetHtml")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetHtml([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = "https://www.stepstone.de/jobs/ausbildung/in-deutschland?page=1";
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                httpClient1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                await Task.Delay(1000); 
                var response = await httpClient1.GetAsync(url);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var htmlContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseData = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
                responseData.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                await responseData.WriteStringAsync(htmlContent);
                return responseData;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"HTTP error occurred: {httpEx.Message}");
                var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
                await errorResponse.WriteStringAsync("Service Unavailable");
                return errorResponse;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                await errorResponse.WriteStringAsync("Internal Server Error");
                return errorResponse;
            }
        }
    }
}

Output :
The below code ran successfully as below.

Browser Output :

Azure Portal :
The HTTP trigger function ran successfully in the Azure Portal as shown below.

I successfully accessed the URL using the function app URL, as shown below.

